# How to connect two gameobjects (ex. with rope) in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

In my game I want player to be connected to another gameobject, so he can't go too far, but can come close to the object. I tried using Spring Joint, but it doesn't allow player to come close to the attached object. Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Connect the objects together using [Hingejoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html). Each object will be attached to the other one using its `Rigidbody` component.

Answer (score 0):

### With Code

We have to draw a circle around the GameObject that you want the player to connect with. We will use the max distance as the radius. If the player gets out of the circle, it will get snapped to the edge of the sphere. Here is the [Visual Explanation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdmDz.png)

---

```
public Transform center; // GameObject to connect
public float maxDistance; // Max distance to move

void LateUpdate()
{        
    float distanceX = center.position.x - transform.position.x; // Distance between center and new position on X axis
    float distanceZ = center.position.z - transform.position.z; // Distance between center and new position on Y axis
    float distance = Mathf.Sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceZ * distanceZ); // Distance between center and new position
    
    if (distance > maxDistance) // If the distance is greater than max distance
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(-distanceZ, -distanceX); // Get the angle between center and new position
        float x = center.position.x + maxDistance * Mathf.Cos(angle); // Get the new position on X axis
        float z = center.position.z + maxDistance * Mathf.Sin(angle); // Get the new position on Y axis
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, z); // Move to the new position
    }
}
```